# getting the same results of all rows while calculating TotalYTD in powerBI

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am getting the same results in every row while calculating the TotalYTD in powerBI. I have a fact table and dimensional date table. My DAX formula is very simple as
**TotalYTD(sum(FactTable(sales), DimDate(Date))**. it gives the same result in every row when use the fields from DimDate table and also fills the empty rows with same results.
Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello! I would include some more information in your post. What does your datamodel look like? What does your end goal visualisation look like? Which columns from which tables are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what do you really need you should change your measure by manipulating a filter context. First use a CALCULATE, SECOND add a good filter statement. For example:

```
YTD = calculate (sum(FactTable[sales]), FILTER(ALL(DimDate), DimDate[Year] = SELECTEDVALUE(DimDate[Year]) && DimDate[Date] <= SELECTEDVALUE(DimDate[Date] ) )
```

If i put DimDate[Date] to visualization and this measure then i get a realy nice output.